# Dynamically add private IP's to Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 modules and each are using count at the resource level to create VM's and network interfaces etc.

I would like to dynamically allow all the private ip's from module 2 in the security group of module 1.

I am able to output the data as tuple or string but I don't know how to transform/split/filter this data and loop so that each value can dynamically become a CIDR entry in the SG.

Example with output as tuple which needs to be input in SG:

Module 2:

```
output "private_ip" {
value = "${aws_network_interface.test[*].private_ip}"
}
```

Module 1:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "SSH" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = ["${var.private_ip}/32"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.test.id
}
```

Parent:

```
module "Module1" {
  source = "./Module1"
  private_ip = "${module.Module2.private_ip}"
}

module "Module2" {
  source = "./Module2"
}
```

When I run the above as is I get the below error:

```
│ Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   on Module1/main.tf line 129, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "SSH":
│  129:   cidr_blocks       = ["${var.private_ip}/32"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.private_ip is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Comment: How do you invoke `Module 1` from the parent module?

Comment: I have the modules defined in a root tf file which is where I pass variables between modules using outputs. I will edit to add the parent as an example.

Comment: Please update the question and show how you are creating the module, pass variables to it, and what errors do you get.

Comment: What is your TF version?

Comment: Terraform v1.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using TF `v1.2.8`, its better to use modern syntax, not syntax from v `0.11`. Also this is how you can pass multiple IPs:

```
output "private_ip" {
   value =  aws_network_interface.test[*].private_ip
}

module "Module1" {
  source = "./Module1"
  private_ip = module.Module2.private_ip
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "SSH" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = [for ip in var.private_ip: "${ip}/32"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.test.id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and recommending best practises. Worked perfectly.